# Have there been any sitting US presidents that regularly consult a former president, even informally?

Tags: united-states, president

A user, [DJClayworth](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/232/djclayworth), asks in a comment (on [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/49582/10172) )

> I wonder how often Trump has consulted Obama for his "wise counsel". Or Obama consulted Bush for that matter.

I'd like to pose this as a more general question here, but with narrow enough scope to be answered. The broader question would be as posed in the title, but perhaps to focus on specific criteria, the question would be, "Starting from the present and working backwards, who was the most recent US president to regularly consult a former president?" (as some of the founding fathers would seem to fit this criteria).

I briefly searched for this online but only saw articles like [this USA today one](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/onpolitics/2016/11/10/obama-trump-white-house-meeting-bush-clinton/93599108/) which seem to imply (at least in modern times) presidents only really meet during a transition period.

Comment: I am not sure you are going to find many references to a president consulting a former president as that is not something that would really come up news wise unless one of them brings it up. I am sure it happens more often early in a presidency but its not something that gets much publicity.

Answer (score 5):

In 1947 Truman invited Herbert Hoover to analyze areas in which the federal government could be improved. Eisenhower invited him to perform a second round in 1953. Wikipedia says Kennedy invited him to do more.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoover_Commission

George W Bush had many cabinet members who worked under his father and would have certainly interacted with his father regularly.